# using dj-stripe to subscribe to multiple subscriptions

Tags: python, django, stripe-payments

I am using dj-stripe in my django app. I can successfully subscribe a user to a plan by doing this:

```
customer.subscribe(plan.name)
```

However, if the user is already subscribed to a plan then the above code overrides the old plan with new one. Instead I would like to ADD a new plan rather than UPDATE (thats what it seems to be doing at the moment). Stripe supports adding multiple subscriptions to a user but I can't find anything in dj-stripe documentation regarding it.

Is it possible to have a customer subscribe to multiple plans using dj-stripe?

Comment: I think that plugin uses a *really* old version of the API hardcoded in the code which is why it's using the old behavior. You'd need to either change that code or create the subscription out of that plugin.

Answer (score 1):

The current stable dj-stripe codebase is, as koopajah pointed out, stuck at a quite old version of the Stripe API. We're working on it though; the ADD functionality you're describing will be available once [this issue](https://github.com/pydanny/dj-stripe/issues/162) is completed.

- @kavdev

UPDATE: Though not ready for release yet (see [#307](https://github.com/kavdev/dj-stripe/issues/307) for what still needs to be done), we have a stable implementation of multiple subscriptions on the 1.0.0 branch.